# Custom Save Action not sending email?

Tags: c#, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I want to get receipient & sender Email address from front-end!

I have created a 'Custom Email Sending' save action at this location: 
"Sitecore/System/Modules/Settings/Save Actions/" & added it on a form's Submit buttons's Save Action.

In 'Custom Email Sending' Action in Content tab in 'Data' section I have declared 'Assembly: ***.Helper, Class:***.Helper.CustomEmail'

and in 'Submit' Section in 'Parameter' field i have declared:
Host:smtp.gmail.com, Port:587, Login:example@gmail.com, Password:*****, IsBodyHtml:true, enableSSL:true

and in 'Editor' fieldsection I have declared 'Editor: control:SendMail.Editor'.

But on click of 'Custom Email Sending' action in form I didn't entered value in To,CC,BCC etc.

And In form I have taken three fields 'To', 'From', 'Message'. All I want is that

- "I want to get receipient & sender address from front-end"

This is my code in CustomEmail.cs class:

```
public class CustomEmail : ISaveAction, ISubmit
    {
        public void Execute(Sitecore.Data.ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
        {
            NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
            foreach (AdaptedControlResult acr in fields)
            {
                formData[acr.FieldName] = acr.Value;
            }
            try
            {
                // get field values of form
                string emailTo = formData["To"];
                string emailFrom = formData["From"];
                string personalMsg = formData["Message"];

                bool result = false;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailFrom) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailTo))
                {
                    // send mail
                    result = SendEmail(emailTo, emailFrom, personalMsg);

                }
                // if mail sending fail then show error massege
                if (result == false)
                {
                    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Some error occcured while sending email", this);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(ex.Message.ToString(), this);
            }
        }


        #region SendEmail function
        /// <summary>
        ///  send mail
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="To"></param>
        /// <param name="From"></param>
        /// <param name="Message"></param>
        public static bool SendEmail(string To, string From, string Message)
        {
            bool result = true;

            try
            {

                MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

                MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress(From);
                mailMsg.From = mailFrom;

                try
                {
                    MailAddress mailTo = new MailAddress(To);
                    mailMsg.To.Add(mailTo);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                mailMsg.Body = Message;
                mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                var smtp = new SmtpClient(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.MailServer, Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.MailServerPort);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mailMsg);
            }
            catch
            {
                result = false;

            }

            return result;
        }



        #endregion

        public void Submit(Sitecore.Data.ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields)
        {
            Execute(formid, fields);
        }

        #region IOnLoad Members

        public void OnLoad(bool isPostback, RenderFormArgs args)
        {


        }

        #endregion
    }
```

In web.config I added code:

```
<setting name="MailServer" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
   <setting name="MailServerUserName" value="***@gmail.com" />
   <setting name="MailServerPassword" value="***" />
   <setting name="MailServerPort" value="587" />

<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

I got this Exception:

- The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
  authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication
  Required. Learn more at

Please resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to add credentials to your SmtpClient.

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.MailServer, Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.MailServerPort);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mailMsg);
```

Comment: This.  Gmail's SMTP server most definitely requires authentication

Comment: Yes now its working. But if want to take 'Sender' from front end(means From field) and don't want to give username & password, then what to do?